# Okta API for modifying user application assignments?

Tags: okta, okta-api

Looking for the developer documentation as to how to modify a users application assignment. I would like to programatically assign, unassign and change the assignment details (ex: roles). So far I can't find that in the developer docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly assign and remove users from applications via the  [Application User Operations](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/apps.html#application-user-operations).

Depending on what logic you're trying to implement, it might be better to:

1. [Assign the users to groups](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/groups.html#add-user-to-group). You can even [setup rules](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/groups.html#create-group-rule) to do this for you automatically based on conditions.
2. [Add the group to the app](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/apps.html#assign-group-to-application)

By using groups rather than assigning users to the app directly, you can automate more of the flow (i.e. users can be assigned to apps automatically based on user properties and conditions), as well as setup [Sign-On, MFA, and password policies](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/policy.html).